# Simple Regex Extraction

Tags: regex

I'm assuming this is pretty simple but I'm going round in circles

```
<img src="\/\/i1.ytimg.com\/vi\/sY1S34973zA\/mqdefault.jpg"
```

I need to extract the sY1S34973zA portion.

I'm using PHP.

Any ideas?

Steve

Comment: [What have you tried in seeking to solve this problem](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What programming language are you using the regex in? Regular expressions differ between programming languages. You've provided a single case, what other examples can you show so that a pattern can be found?

Comment: Exactly as @zzzzBov comments, we need a bit more than this. If you were using Python, for example, I would recommend you DIDN'T use regex and instead did something like `text.split(r"\/")[-2]`

Comment: What's the go with that escaping? Show a few more examples please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<img src="[^"]+\/([^"\/]+)\/[^"]*"
```

The folder name is captured and can be replaced as $1.

I'm a little confused by the backslashes. Are you saying the backslashes are part of the string, or are they simply escaping the forward slashes in whatever language you're using?

If the latter, you'll need to make an adjustment or two above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
[^/]+(?=\/[^\/]*$
```